# Showing that $b \leq \frac{b}{\frac{1}{4}+b^2} \Leftrightarrow b^2-2b+\frac{1}{4} \leq 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For an ODE where the solution should be on the interval $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ it has to be $b \leq \frac{b}{\frac{1}{4}+b^2}$.

The task is:

Let $f: [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]\times[-b,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y):=x^2+y^2$. Find $b>0$ with the theorem of Picard-Lindelöf such that the IVP $y'=f(x,y),\ y(0)=0$ has an unique solution for all $|x|\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

The solution says

$b \leq \frac{b}{\frac{1}{4}+b^2} \Leftrightarrow b^2-2b+\frac{1}{4} \leq 0$.

So $b \in [1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 1+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}]$.

I get $b^3-\frac{3}{4}b \leq 0$, so $b\leq \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}$ or $b \in [0, \frac{\sqrt3}{2}]$.

How to get $b \leq \frac{b}{\frac{1}{4}+b^2} \Leftrightarrow b^2-2b+\frac{1}{4} \leq 0$?

Comment: It is not true: if $b=0$ then the LHS is true and the RHS is false.

Comment: You are checking the convergence of the Picard iteration on some ODE? Could you give the ODE and the step leading to the first inequality?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I added the task.

Comment: I get the same solution that you get. $b \leq \frac{b}{\frac{1}{4}+b^2} \Leftrightarrow b^2-2b+\frac{1}{4} \leq 0$ is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "butterfly" (double cone) condition that you have to check is that
$$
Ma\le b,
$$
with $a,b$ the sizes of the box under consideration, $a=\frac12$, and $M=a^2+b^2=\frac14+b^2$ the maximum of the function value inside the box. Inserted this gives
$$
\frac12(\frac14+b^2)\le b\iff \frac14-2b+b^2\le 0.
$$

---

To compute a non-constant upper bound, one can check that for the differential inequality
$$
|y'|\le \frac14+y^2
$$
one gets
$$
|y(x)|\le\frac12\tan(\frac{|x|}2),
$$
so that in principle the height $b=\frac12\tan(\frac14)$ is sufficient to contain the solution inside the box.